# zsh prefix completion is gone when running in tmux

Tags: zsh, tmux, autocomplete

The prefix completion in `zsh` using up and down arrow arrow keys is amazing. Let's assume I have the following command history:

1. `ls ~`
2. `vim .zshrc`
3. `ls /tmp`
4. `cat /tmp/wiefoijewfoijwef`
5. `ls /etc`

Then, when I type `ls` and press arrow up, it will propose only options 5,3 and 1.

Unfortunately, when launched within `tmux`, the feature is gone and arrow keys offer only simple history browsing (5,4,3,2,1). Why? And how can I change that?

Comment: That's not a feature that's enabled by default. Either your up/down arrow keys send the same sequences as Alt+P Alt+N or you have something in one of your configuration files that binds Up/Down to `history-search-{for,back}ward`, possibly binding to the specific sequence of characters that Up/Down sends in your other terminal (maybe only with/without `tput smkx`) and that doesn't match what tmux itself sends. Does pressing Ctr+V followed by Up or Down show different things inside and outside tmux?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be within my `.zshrc`. There was a part of code redefining keybindings, which tried to recognize the terminal. However, `tmux*` did not match the glob of `xterm*`.